# Remove selection from layer in an svg

Tags: vector, inkscape, layers, selections

I'm a complete amateur and just googling my way around but I'm a bit lost with the current task.

I'm editing the following SVG graphic in Inkscape: https://chaosdata.deviantart.com/art/BackTrack-Dragon-SVG-206730858

The goal is a vector graphic of the dragon alone, with it's eye cut out, so it is transparent. I'm trying to select the eye and delete the selection on the body layer of the dragon. At least that's what I would do with a non-vector graphic. I can simply delete the eye, but that leaves a solid area beneath.

[image: eyeofthedragon]

How can I remove the eye from the graphic and delete the shape from the layer beneath?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. select the eye and copy it using <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> (Copy)
2. select both the grey dragon shape and the yellow triangle, by clicking on each with the Nodes tool <kbd>F2</kbd>, while holding down <kbd>Shift</kbd> to make a multiple selection.
3. click *Path > Difference*

[image]

4. Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> (Paste in Place) and the eye will be pasted back in the same position as it was previously
5. select both the black background and the yellow eye
6. click *Path > Difference*

[image]

Now the eye is cut out of both the grey dragon shape, and the black background behind, leaving the space fully transparent.

If instead you want to remove the entire black background select it with the Nodes tool <kbd>F2</kbd> and then switch to the Select tool <kbd>F1</kbd> and hit <kbd>Delete</kbd>

Example showing background completely removed

[image]